# Sorting by alpabetical order on Priority Queue

Tags: python

That's my function below, I am trying to separate the whole words by their first character. For example, "red, blue" should be resulted like that "blue, red"

```
def isInAlphabeticalOrder(word):

    word1=sorted(word)
    return(word1)


print(isInAlphabeticalOrder("blue, yellow, green, red"))
```

It shows;

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', ',', ',', ',', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'g', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'n', 'o', 'r', 'r', 'u', 'w', 'y']
```

I want my result to be in this manner;

```
("blue, green, red, yellow")
```

Comment: You should split your input string. Or you should use lists

Answer (score 4):

Python strings are iterable, so you're sorting the individual characters.

You probably want to

1. split the string into a list of colors
2. sort the list of strings
3. possibly re-join it.

e.g.:

```
def alphabetize(word):
    words_split = word.split(', ')
    words_split.sort()
    return ', '.join(words_split)
```